# clang can’t find built in C headers on iOS

Tags: c, objective-c, iphone, clang, header-files

I’m trying to build a C project on my iPhone, but I’m getting this error:[image: String.h not found?! But that is a built-in C header!]
Can anyone help? I have installed everything from clang dependencies through APT.

Comment: post code, not the image

Comment: from the link looks like the `S` is capital use `#include<string.h>`

Comment: Are you able to compile a "hello world" program that includes string.h?

Comment: It turns out I forgot to point the compiler to my /usr/include directory...